# Laravel - Editing a dropdown option in a form

Tags: php, laravel, html-select

I'm building a CRUD app in laravel. In my create form I have users select an option from a dropdown and that values posts to the database.

I'm attempting to edit that form now, but I can't get the value dynamically using a for each loop. But I can manually.

This is what works but it's not dynamic

```
<select class ="form-control" id="type" name="type">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option {{ $Advert->type == 'Apartment' ? 'selected':'' }}>Apartment</option>
    <option {{ $Advert->type == 'House' ? 'selected':'' }}>House</option>
    <option {{ $Advert->type == 'Studio' ? 'selected':'' }}>Studio</option>
    <option {{ $Advert->type == 'Flat' ? 'selected':'' }}>Flat</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to generate the value in the edit using a foreach loop but i'm getting the error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Here is the code for the foreach

```
  <select class ="form-control" id="type" name="type">
      @foreach ($Advert as $type)
          <option {{ $type->type == $Advert->type ? 'selected':'' }}>{{$type->type}}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
```

VARDUMP on $advert

```
object(App\PropertyAdvert)#216 (26) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(5) "photo" [1]=> string(7) "address" [2]=> string(6) "county" [3]=> string(4) "town" [4]=> string(4) "type" [5]=> string(4) "rent" [6]=> string(4) "date" [7]=> string(8) "bedrooms" [8]=> string(9) "bathrooms" [9]=> string(9) "furnished" [10]=> string(11) "description" [11]=> string(7) "user_id" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["photo"]=> string(12800) "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" ["address"]=> string(12) "42 Park Vale" ["county"]=> string(6) "Dublin" ["town"]=> string(8) "Baldoyle" ["type"]=> string(5) "House" ["rent"]=> string(4) "1000" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-04-22" ["bedrooms"]=> string(1) "3" ["bathrooms"]=> string(1) "2" ["furnished"]=> string(7) "option1" ["description"]=> string(8) "efewfwef" ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-02-25 18:50:37" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-02-25 18:50:37" } ["original":protected]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> int(2)  ["address"]=> string(12) "42 Park Vale" ["county"]=> string(6) "Dublin" ["town"]=> string(8) "Baldoyle" ["type"]=> string(5) "House" ["rent"]=> string(4) "1000" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-04-22" ["bedrooms"]=> string(1) "3" ["bathrooms"]=> string(1) "2" ["furnished"]=> string(7) "option1" ["description"]=> string(8) "efewfwef" ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-02-25 18:50:37" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-02-25 18:50:37" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } }
```

Comment: Your foreach loop does not make any sense. Your are using $type variable in a wrong way. Correct that first by giving a different name.

Comment: What is the result when you've output the `$Advert` variable? `var_dump($Advert); exit;` in your `controller`? Maybe the `type` property does not exist in `$type`

Comment: i'm compacting $advert from the controller. I access as the variables in other parts of the form like $advert->title. The properties are in the same table.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi what's wrong with the foreach loop?

Comment: Can you please print your $Advert varaible and update your question

Comment: Done. But theres alot in it

Comment: I have it working. I wasn't compacting types in the edit controller, only create

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="male"@if($phone->gender=='male') selected='selected' @endif >Male</option>
```

i have tried . this is best solution. you can try and enjoy

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you want to edit this `$Advert` object, then you must pass this object to the view ALONG with every available options that you get from database. For example

In your controller:

```
$Advert = Advert::find($id)
$advert_types = // all the types that you'll get from your database
// maybe something like this
// $advert_types = DB::table('types')->get();
return view('yourview', compact('$Advert', 'advert_types'));
```

In your view, you want to write this:

```
<select class ="form-control" id="type" name="type">
  @foreach ($advert_types as $type)
    <option {{ $type->type == $Advert->type ? 'selected':'' }}>{{$type->type}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Then you'll get your code done. You just cannot do foreach in single object ($Advert), that's why you get the error

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
$advert = Advert::find($id)
$advert_types = Advert::pluck('name', 'id');
return view('yourview', compact('$advert', 'advert_types'));
```

Your view:

```
<select class ="form-control" id="type" name="type">
@foreach ($advert_types as $key => $value)
<option disable="true" value="{{ $key }}" {{ ($key == $advert) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$value}}
</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<option {{ $Advert->type == 'Apartment' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34887845)